# Browserify dynamic separate bundles

Tags: javascript, browserify, commonjs

My app loads an object of messages in a given language into the application. My structure is like so:

```
/lang
    /en.js (100 kb file)
    /ru.js (100 kb file)
    /... many more
app.js (this is `MyApp` as below)
```

The language files are very big so I would like to create separate bundles and you then only include the files you need `<script src="lang/en.js"></script>`. The language can also be 'switched' within the application at any time.

How would I tell browserify to build the main app and separate bundles for all the language files, and still allow `MyApp` to `require` those language files?

```
function MyApp(lang) {
    this.messages = {};
    this.switchLang(lang);
};

MyApp.prototype.loadLang = function(lang) {
    this.messages = require('./lang/' + lang + '.js');
};

MyApp.prototype.switchLang = function(lang) {
    this.lang = lang;
    this.loadLang(lang);
};

MyApp.prototype.sayHello = function() {
    alert(this.messages.HELLO);
};

module.exports = MyApp;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can separate all languages from your main app by using `-r` (require) and `-x` (external) in your `browserify` command.

Bundle languages together to one file, could look like this:

```
browserify -r ./lang/en.js -r ./lang/ru.js > languages.js
```

> RECOMMENDED: You can create a separate bundle for each language file with the above command. Just use `-r` once.

Then include the new file (`languages.js`) in your html page **before** `MyApp.js`. Then you have to ignore them while building `MyApp.js`.

```
browserify --ignore-missing -x ./lang/en.js -x ./lang/ru.js -d app.js > MyApp.js
```

You are still allowed to `require` those languages.

> NOTE: If you have a separate bundle for each language (see `RECOMMENDED`), you are only allowed to `require` the included ones in your main app.

There is no browserify-way to do that automatically for each file in `lang/`.

> I recommend you to write a `*.cmd` (batch) file that executes the above commands for every language file in `lang/`. So you can still include your favored language.

EDIT: use `--ignore-missing` or `--im` when bundleing `MyApp.js`. So you can `require` all languages and when they are missing they are still `undefined`.

Comment: Thanks this is a great help! When running `browserify -x ./lang/en.js ....` that doesn't add references to the other language files, so when the `MyApp.js` trys to require them it doesn't know where they are. I think it's because the lang files are being `required` dynamically in `loadLang`, so browserify doesn't pick up on them. I've hacked it in by adding a function that never get's called with all the lang file requires like `require('./lang/en.js')` and `require('./lang/ru.js')` that works. Seems a bit hacky though? Also getting some weird windows path issue.

Comment: `that doesn't add references to the other language files, so when the MyApp.js trys to require them it doesn't know where they are.` yes, you can ONLY require language files, when they are included in your html page before `MyApp.js`. I will edit my answer for a other/better solution...